# execute a jar file by assigning it to a button injava fxml

Tags: java, fxml

I have a sample FXML code with single button.

```
protected void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("The button was clicked!");
    }
}
```

`dosomething()` is the button Id. If I click on that button, it displays that the button was clicked. What is the proper syntax if I want to execute a jar file instead of displaying the text?

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose your jar is named `myJar.jar` then

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java","-jar","myJar.jar"});
 process.waitFor();
 java.io.InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
 byte[] myByte = new byte[inputStream.available()];
 inputStream.read(myByte, 0, myByte.length);
 System.out.println(new String(myByte));
```